# Can we rephrase this question to make it fit?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, closing

So this question got asked earlier by a new user:

[How do I see my inputs?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/153277/how-do-i-see-my-inputs)

It got put on hold because it seemed to be more about development tools than gaming. However in the comments, the user mentioned that he thought it would fit here because it's specific to using his emulator.

In my opinion this is really great question. He obviously put a lot of thought it to it, and it does have an answer.

I'm wondering if there's a way to make this more gaming-specific so we can keep it around? I feel like it might be useful but I don't know much about emulators or inputs or development, etc so I don't think I'm the person to do it. Thoughts? :)

Comment: This is a great example of the proper treatment of new users!  This guy asked a very well reasoned, well researched question which was unfortunately off-topic. And, @spugsley went out of her way to help!  You deserve a pat on the back for this!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the comment he left on my answer:

> So this method, which I am aware of, doesn't really help. Yes, it identifies the buttons, but not how the buttons are referred to programatically... it's the same display regardless of xinput or dinput controller being attached, yes, the one lights up when I press the corresponding button, but what is that button called (Button1 vs Button One vs BttnOne vs all the different ways you can say it that could work but don't, since only some names are recognized as being that input). As for using in controller scripts to load into the emulators or other scripting tools to add functions to my games

He's not looking to see which button is referred to what by Windows, or any other OS; he's looking for how to refer to them for scripting purposes.  That's outside our purview, unfortunately.  Since this is a programming related question, though, perhaps StackOverflow would be a better place for him to ask this.

Comment: @Jack I have to agree with Frank here. Good question, but wrong forum.   StackOverflow is probably a better fit.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you Spugsley.

@Frank... I am looking for exactly how Windows is seeing the input, just how it sees it is actually different for xinputs and dinputs, but on the Windows controller set up, it doesn't refer the name of the buttons, it just lights a marker with a number... This doesn't tell me what Windows calls this button.  Let's say for example, it calls it Button1... I can pretty much put a send:Button1 into things like a script, or my emulator's controller config file.  This is especially for the axis, where the controller tool on Windows just (again) gives a general reference.  But is it actually LeftAxisY or LAxis_Y or just AxisY or Yaxis?  See how the tool is missing info that can be useful?  Ofcourse I'd also love to see to +- and degree of motion... just like I'd like to see the hid inputs of devices because my controllers (apparently) also use hid input functions, and I don't even know how those are mapped or referenced in Widows.

P.S. I tried Stack Overflow first, and got no response... thought because of it's gaming tie this might work.

Comment: `P.S. I tried Stack Overflow first, and got no response... thought because of it's gaming tie this might work.` - This is basically the worst reason to do this. As Frank notes, development tools are pretty explicitly off topic here for the most part.

Comment: so the worst reason to ask a question is because you don't have an answer.  Good to know.  And why are people hung up on "this is a development question"... if I asked, which is the typical "action" button on playstation 3, vs on an xbox, would that be ok?.. because I'm asking what a buttons name is on windows when you use an xinput vs dinput controller for use with my emulator.  I think it's similar and about gaming... this isn't deeply technical super obscure knowledge, I just don't happen to know and the search terms produce lots of results unrelated to what I am looking for.

Comment: It's not so much you not getting an answer, as deciding to ask the same question on more than one site.  Crossposting is generally frowned upon, as it fragments the effort to help you.  We are primarily about *gaming*, and it's relevant skills and expertise.  Knowing how Windows refers to keypresses is rather far outside what can be expected of our skillset.

Comment: I guess I see your point in terms of the StackExchange sites being more or less one... I guess I perceived them as more seperate, but I guess given that I (still) believe this is relevant to gaming (and I'm not totally alone, or this post wouldn't exist, though I see it is a small minority, so far as have spoken up), I also though that given I got no response whatsoever to my previous post and not thoroughly thinking out the interconnectedness/hoping targeting other gamers (because of it's gaming relation in my mind) would help.

Comment: I did think of another way to phrase the question maybe... whether or not it's any more acceptable: how do the buttons change on Windows OS when I use a PS# style controller vs Xbox controller?  (the ps controllers and any styled from it use dinput, the xbox uses xinput)... I'm also close to actually figuring this out on my own, I think.  I am sorry about the mess I guess, though I guess I also wish people responses would be more helpful in terms of trying to actually point me in a useful direction, thus also answering the question and finishing things quicker, perhaps.  Thanks all.

Comment: Last thing: any good thoughts on where I could post this info when I figure it out?  I don't want to clog these sites with any more of my crap, but this might be useful to someone else (like anyone who wants/needs to use a controller to play a pc game that only supports a keyboard, to add more custom functions to their controller in games that already support it via button combo macros and scripts, and to fully adjust settings in emulators, like trying to configure all the functions of the combined wiimote + nunchuck mapped properly to an xbox360 or ps3 controller, for example... more uses?)

Comment: @Jack: You might want to try linking to your StackOverflow post from your post here on Gaming. This way, people who see your question and are interested in it here (it seems like it's getting quite a bit of attention) can go ahead and answer it on the board where it's on topic.

Comment: @jack you might get some help at http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/